# Ubuntu lets me know an upgrade is available; never Installs It

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

I use Lubuntu. For the past few weeks I've been getting a notification that a new version of the OS is available, but whenever I hit <kbd>upgrade</kbd> it does nothing.

At first I overlooked it since I thought maybe I'd noticed something new as I restarted my computer, but upon doing that -- and more -- the notification for me to upgrade keeps popping up, and I keep authenticating it without it ever going through.

Since this is a problem with the software updater itself, the Ubuntu instructions didn't help, since it says to simply use software updater, bringing me back to the problem.

So what's the goof?

Comment: Have you updated your current OS with everything to date before trying the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

upgrade via the terminal then since this sounds like a bug. It might be fixed already so I suggest you upgrade and report back if it's still an issue.

check what updates that are available with (always do this first):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install those upgrades with (this will install all upgrades available):

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and install new kernels with: (Do not confuse this with do-release-upgrade since that upgrades the computer to a new release)

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you wanna do it in one command here it is:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried the bottom command, but it says nothing was upgraded:

"0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 0 not upgraded."

Odd to spend all that time telling me to upgrade and then not do it. 

Ah, and it's stopped telling me to upgrade too.

Comment: @Benjamin That means that the upgrades were installed at some point.